# Java-annotation parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm experimenting with Kotlin and I have a following Java-annotation

```
@Target( { TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface View {
    String[] url() default "";
    Class<? extends Component> parent() default Component.class;
}
```

and in Java-code it is used in following way

```
@View(url="/", parent=RootView.class)
public class FrontView extends Component {
}
```

How is that expressed in Kotlin? I have tried

```
[View(url=Array<String>("/"), parent=Class<RootView>)]
class FrontView : Component() {
}
```

but it does not compile. I only get type mismatch errors.

```
Type mismatch.  
Required: jet.Array<jet.String?>?  
Found: jet.Array<T>
```

and

```
Type mismatch
Required: java.lang.Class<out net.contextfw.web.application.component.Component?>?
Found: java.lang.Class<T>
```

Comment: Full docs for annotations are at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html

Comment: Beginner here. I had the error: "Parameters must have type annotation" for the code `val isHidden:? Boolean`. The correct code should be `val isHidden: Boolean?` (to define a Optional val).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution. The syntax seems to be like this:

```
[View(url=array("/"), parent=javaClass<RootView>())]
class FrontView() : Component() {
}
```

Comment: Yeah dropping [] would make it look cleaner.

Comment: The syntax has changed, in Kotlin now annotations use @ and are consistent with the Java syntax.  Additional syntax is for targeting an annotation when there is more than one option.  Full docs are now at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html